# JitterBit vs Dell Boomi vs Celigo

Tags: salesforce, middleware, jitterbit, boomi, ipaas

We've narrowed our selection for an ipaas down to the above 3.

Initially we're looking to pass data from a cloud based HR system to Netsuite, and from Netsuite to Salesforce, and sometimes JIRA.

i've come from a Mulesoft background which I think would be too complex for this. On the other hand it seems that Celigo is VERY drag and drop, and there's not much room for modification/customisation.

Of the three, do you have any experience/recommendations? We aren't looking for any code heavy custom APIs, most will just be simple scheduled data transfers but there may be some complexity within the field mapping, and we want to set ourselves up for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few years removing Celigo from NetSuite and Salesforce.  The best way I can describe Celigo is that it is like the old school anti-virus programs which were often worse than the viruses... lol...  It digs itself into the end system, making removing it a nightmare.

Boomi does the job, but is very counter-intuitive, and overly complex.  You can't do everything from one screen, you can't easily bounce back and forth between tasks/operations/etc.  And, sometimes it is very difficult to find where endpoints are used, as they are not always shown in their "where is this used" feature.  Boomi has a ton of endpoint connectors pre-built (the most, I believe), but I have not seen an easy way to just create your own.  Boomi also has much more functionality than just the integrations, if that is something that may be needed.

Jitterbit, my favorite, is ridiculously simple to use.  You can access everything from one main screen, you can connect to anything (as long as it can reach out to the network, or you can reach it via the network - internal or external).  Jitterbit has a lot of pre-built endpoint connectors.  It is also extremely easy to just create a connection to anything you want.  The win with Jitterbit is that it is super easy to use, super easy to learn, it always works, they have amazing support (if you need it).  I have worked with Jitterbit the most (about 6 years), and I have never been unable to complete an integration task in less that a couple of day, max.

Answer (score 2):

I have extensive experience with Dell Boomi platform but none with JitterBit or Celigo. Dell Boomi offers very versatile and well supported iPaaS solution. The technical challenges of Boomi are some UI\usability issues (@W3BGUY mentioned the main ones) and the lack of out-of-the-box support for CI/CD and DevOps processes (code management, versioning, deployments etc.)

One more important component to consider here is the pricing of the platform. Boomi does charge their clients yearly connection prices. Connection is defined as a unique combination of URL, username and password. The yearly license costs vary and can range anywhere between ($1,000 - $12,000) per license per year. The price depends greatly on your integration landscape and the discounts provided so I would advise on engaging with vendor early to understand your costs. Would be great to hear from others on pricing for JitterBit and Celigo.

Boomi is also more than just an iPaaS platform. They offer other modules of their platform to customers: API Management, Boomi Flow (workflow and automation module), Master Data Hub (master data management). Some of these modules are well developed and some are in their infancy (API Management).

From my limited experience with MuleSoft platform, I share the OP's sentiments about it being too complex for simple integrations. They do provide great CI/CD and DevOps functionality though if that is something that is needed.

There is not a simple answer to a question like this. One needs to look at multiple aspects of the platform and make a decision based on multitude of factors. I would advise looking at [Gartner](https://www.gartner.com/en/documents/3907109/magic-quadrant-for-enterprise-integration-platform-as-a-) and [Forrester](https://www.forrester.com/report/The+Forrester+Wave+Strategic+iPaaS+And+Hybrid+Integration+Platforms+Q1+2019/-/E-RES141621) reports for a general guidelines and working out the pricing (initial and recurring) with the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I have only used Jitterbit, so can only comment on that. It works fine. It is pretty intuitive and easy to use, but does have some flexibility with writing your own queries, defining and mapping file formats, and choosing different transfer protocols.
I've only used the free version (which you need to host somewhere and also is not supported) and it was good enough for production tasks. If you have the luxury of time, I'd say download it and try it out. If it works for you, throw it on a server or upgrade to the cloud version.
One note: Jitterbit uses background services. If you run it locally and then decide to migrate your account to a server, you need to stop those services on your local. Otherwise, it will try to run jobs from both locations and that doesn't turn out well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out [Choreo](https://wso2.com/choreo/) as well. It has a novel simultaneous code + low-code approach for integration development. And provides rich AI support for performance monitoring, debugging, and data mapping.

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the project.